# Member modified by method reverts after it exits

Tags: oop, winapi, d

I have a window (Windows), and my wndProc is basically the same as the one on the windows guides. However, even though WM_CLOSE gets passed (and I can use if(msg == WM_CLOSE)), I can't seem to set my shouldClose flag. I've confirmed that I still get the event within my processMessage method. So my question is this: what is going on, and how can I make it work?

Edit: I tried storing the window data as a struct instead of a class, and everything works just fine. Ie. All I changed was the type of the class, and a few errors.

```
class Win32Window {
    this(wstring title, int width, int height) {
        immutable wstring className = "glass_def_class_name\0";
        auto hInstance = GetModuleHandle(null);

        WNDCLASSW wc;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = &windowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.lpszClassName = &className[0];
        RegisterClassW(&wc);

        handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,
            &className[0],
            &title[0],
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            width, height,
            null, null,
            hInstance,
            cast(void*) this);

        ShowWindow(handle, SW_NORMAL);
    }

    ~this() {
        DestroyWindow(handle);
    }

    void processEvents() {
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, handle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    bool shouldClose;
    HWND handle;

private:
    LRESULT processMessage(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) nothrow {
        switch (msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            shouldClose = true;
            return 0;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(handle, msg, wp, lp);
        }
    }
}

private extern (Windows) LRESULT windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) nothrow {
    Win32Window window;

    if (msg == WM_CREATE) {
        CREATESTRUCT* create = cast(CREATESTRUCT*) lp;
        window = cast(Win32Window*) create.lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, cast(LONG_PTR) create.lpCreateParams);
        window.handle = hwnd;
    }
    else {
        LONG_PTR ptr = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        window = cast(Win32Window* ptr);
    }

    if (window)
        return window.processMessage(msg, wp, lp);
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

void main()
{
    auto window = new Win32Window("test", 1280, 720);
    while(window.shouldClose == false) {
        window.processEvents();
    }
    window.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove all the relevant code. Show a MCVE.

Comment: An MCVE is a lot of code. Especially for window creation. I can certainly do so though.

Comment: It's only a lot if you don't cut it down. That's the M.

Comment: It's almost a hundred loc with it as small as I know how to make it. I'm editing the question now

Comment: `Win32Window window =  *(cast(Win32Window*) ptr);` you are create local copy of class on every windows message ?!? of course all your modifications is done to this local copy and lost all time when you exit from windowproc

Comment: Huh, let me fix that. I was under the impression that dereferencing a pointer to an object returns a reference to it. Anyway, that seems to have fixed the Access Violation error, but I still can't make my modification persist.

Comment: Side note: iirc, the earliest message sent to a window is `WM_NCCREATE`; attach your object and subclass there, rather than in `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: if I understand your code (I don't know language on which you write) - you make local copy of your initial object state in `windowProc` and then do all modification **to this local copy** - of course all it lost when you exit from `windowProc`... but when I view your code in `main` .. `window.shouldClose` but not `window->shouldClose`, `window.processEvents();` but not `window->processEvents();` - I understand that you use unknown to me language. I don understand where object, where pointer to object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't actually cast a pointer directly to a reference. An intermediary is necessary (or something to that effect). Thus, the `winProc` should look something like this:

```
private extern (Windows) LRESULT windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) nothrow {
    Win32Window window;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) {
        auto create = cast(CREATESTRUCT*) lp;
        window = cast(Win32Window) (cast(void*) create.lpCreateParams);
        window.handle = hwnd;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, cast(LONG_PTR) create.lpCreateParams);
    }
    else {
        window = cast(Win32Window) (cast(void*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    }

    return window ? window.processMessage(msg, wp, lp) : DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Note the extra `cast(void*)` before `create.lpCreateParams` and `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)`. I'm not entirely sure why this works as opposed to my original code, but it seems to work, and I'll do some more investigating when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Member modified by method reverts after it exits

this was when you worked with local copy of object, and make modification to this local copy, but not really to object. I not view another explanations

inside `windowProc` you do next `Win32Window window = *(cast(Win32Window*) ptr);` - so you make local copy of your initial object state in `windowProc` and then do all modification **to this local copy** - of course all it lost when you exit from `windowProc` correct code must be next:

```
private LRESULT windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) nothrow {
    Win32Window* window;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) {
        CREATESTRUCT* create = (CREATESTRUCT*) lp;
        window = (Win32Window*) create.lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) create.lpCreateParams);
        window.handle = hwnd;
    }
    else {
        window = (Win32Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }

    return window ? window->processMessage(msg, wp, lp) : DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. It removes the Access Violation error, but the value still remains un-persistent.

Comment: By using `*(cast(Win32Window*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)` it is my understanding that you get the reference (as opposed to a pointer) to the object. All objects in D are reference types by default.

Comment: @Straivers - so you still not fix, in-persist this mean you work not with pointer to object but with local copy of object. miracles not exist. I completely not understand your code in `main` too. this is error when you do copy/paste or real code snipet ? here `auto window`- pointer or local copy of object. I at all unfamiliar with language on which you write

Comment: Sorry, I've been unclear. I've translated the code you used, and it resolves the error. However, I still cannot change `shouldClose`. `auto window` refers to a reference, which is basically a pointer, but disallows pointer arithmetic. This is a real code snippet that I'm working on right now (copied out of editor).

Comment: @Straivers - sorry, I not note at begin that you write on `d` language. I nothing know about it and try interpret code from `c++` view. but main my think - you work with not real pointer to object but with copy. I say from c++/ window view. I don't know what is `reference`